# '2 of 3 tests passed' when only 2 test methods were exported

Tags: unit-testing, firefox-addon-sdk

This is `test-main.js`, basically the default after running `cfx init` ..

```
var main = require("./main");

exports["test main"] = function(assert) {
  assert.pass("Unit test running!");
};

exports["test main async"] = function(assert, done) {
  assert.pass("async Unit test running!");
  done();
};

require("sdk/test").run(exports);
```

And this is the output, why does it say `2 of 3 tests passed`?
When there is only 2 test methods exported.

```
[rob@laptop addon]$ ~/apps/addon-sdk-1.17/bin/cfx test
Using binary at '/usr/bin/firefox'.
Using profile at '/tmp/tmpdrQaVV.mozrunner'.
Running tests on Firefox 31.1.0/Gecko 31.1.0 ({ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}) under linux/x86_64.
console.warn: addon: Plural form unknown for locale "null"
System JS : ERROR chrome://browser/content/browser.js:14338 - TypeError: value is not a non-null object
System JS : ERROR chrome://browser/content/content-sessionStore.js:230 - TypeError: docShell.QueryInterface(...).sessionHistory is null
console.error: addon: 
  warnings and/or errors were logged.

2 of 3 tests passed.
Total time: 3.634853 seconds
Program terminated unsuccessfully.
```

Comment: The number of failed tests (hence total number of tests) is increased by 1 in a cleanup function from the test harness (file `lib/sdk/test/harness.js`) because of your add-on logging a warning. This warning comes from localization: when running your tests the SDK does not seem to set a locale for Fx, and then search plural rules for resulting "null" locale (whichs fails and return the warning). I haven't found how to fix it.